# Use of In operator with WebSQL with an array

Tags: javascript, web-sql

```
searchSQL: "SELECT * FROM FOLIO where productID IN(?)",

search: function(q, productIds) {
    var self = this;
    this.database.transaction(function(transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql(self.searchSQL, [productIds.join(", ")], function(transaction, resultSet){self.search_transactionComplete(transaction, resultSet)}, function(error){self.searchTransactionError()});
    });
},

search_transactionComplete: function(transaction, resultSet) {
    console.log(transaction, resultSet);
},

searchTransactionError: function(error) {console.log(this.constructor.NAME, this.searchSQL); console.log(error);},
```

Can anyone please suggest that how can I use IN operator with an passed array (productIds) in WebSQL/Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is probably a bit late, but in case anyone else runs into this problem, here's my hacky workaround. I know it's not ideal, but as far as I know, webSQL doesn't support array-type parameters; my solution dynamically generates the sql, and passes each item in the product array as a separate paramater.

```
search: function(q, productIds) {
var self = this;

if (productIds.length == 0) {
    //no-op
} else {
    //make a copy of the productIds array
    var paramList = productIds.slice();

    //replace all values in the array with a parameter-placeholder
    for (var ii = 0; ii < paramList.length; ii++) {
        paramList[ii] = '?';
    }

    //convert the list of parameters to a comma-delimited string
    var sParamList = paramList.join();

    //we know sParamList is clean, it can only contain commas and question marks
    var hackySql = "SELECT * FROM FOLIO where productID IN(" + sParamList + ")";

    //hackySQL looks like: "SELECT * FROM FOLIO WHERE productID IN(?,?,?,?,?,?)"

    this.database.transaction(function(transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql(hackySql, productIds,   function(transaction, resultSet){self.search_transactionComplete(transaction, resultSet)}, function(error){self.searchTransactionError()});
    })
}}
```

Hope this helps someone else!